# Returning A Keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, return

Im trying to use Code Academy tutorial to return a keyword with the following:-

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
   var timesTwo = function(number) {
   return number * 2;
   };

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = timesTwo;
console.log(newNumber);
```

Ive tried and it isnt returning a number :S

i tried the below:-

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
return number * 2;
};

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = function (timesTwo) {
    return 20 * timesTwo;
};
console.log(newNumber);
```

Please can someone give me a pointer as to where i maybe going wrong please (i apologise, i am a new person to JS)

Comment: u havn't invoke the function.. invoked by timesTwo();

Comment: Your terminology is wrong here. `return` _is_ a keyword. What you return is a _value_

Comment: Think about what number you're expecting it to output - you've told it how to multiply by two, and then you're trying to say "now do it", but you haven't anywhere said _what_ you're timesing by two.

Comment: as mentioned i apologise i am trying to learn this and its very new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a number in as a parameter.

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = timesTwo(5);
console.log(newNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`console.log(timesTwo(20));`

This is what is actually happening in your code:

```
// variable timesTwo is a function
   var timesTwo = function(number) {
   return number * 2;
   };

// newNumber is set to the same function as timesTwo
// newNumber is thus also a variable with a function
var newNumber = timesTwo;

//This will then of course output the function of timesTwo e.g.
// function(number) {
//   return number * 2;
// };
console.log(newNumber);
```

If you want execute the function add the parentheses `()`.
If you want to add an argument to the function add it between them e.g. `(20)`.
This can also be a variable if you want e.g. `(number)`.

Comment: This question is clearly made by a complete beginner. A simple explanation could have been very useful. Telling the novice just what to do, and not _why_ to do it is not, IMHO

**E**: Removed the downvote

Answer (score 1):

you can return value in this way also:

**Example:**

```
function myFunction(number)
{
     return number*2;
}

var newValue= myFunction(5);

console.log(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
   var timesTwo = function(number) {
   return number * 2;
   };

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = timesTwo(numbertosquare);
console.log(newNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
var myvariable = function() { /* DO SOMETHING */ };
```

You are assigning an anonymous function to a variable. So if you try to call `myvariable` without the function invocation syntax `myvariable()` it won't work.

In your case:

```
// Assign function to variable
var timesTwo = function(number) { return number * 2; };
// call function
timesTwo(2);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

timesTwo is an object reference for the function. Your function needs a number for math calculation. so you need to pass a number using the object. refer
 the function like this: **timesTwo(5)**

```
/* timesTwo is used to reference the function.Function can trigger only through the  
   timesTwo object.
*/
 var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
  };

 // Call function here
 var num=8;
 var newNumber = timesTwo(num); //stores result to newNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
    console.log(newNumber(timesTwo(1)));//40
```

`timesTwo()` function need parament which you have not passed it

CASE 1

```
//here var timesTwo is assigned function not value
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

//here var newNumber is assigned function
var newNumber = timesTwo;
console.log(newNumber(5));// 10
```

CASE 2

```
//here var timesTwo is assigned function not value
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

//here var newNumber is assigned value return from timesTwo function
var newNumber = timesTwo(5);
console.log(newNumber);// 10
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want this to work in simple form for codeacatomy.com you'll need to be very basic with it.

var newNumber = timesTwo(4);
console.log(newNumber);

replace the bottom half with this and it will allow you to pass. it's only asking for you to define a number for timesTwo.